# GUICE Dependency Injection to normal class

Tags: java, guice

I need to understand how to bind and inject the object to a normal class as below:

```
Exampl1: Want to inject B Obj to the class, here i dont have any constructor.
class A {
 @Inject private B obj;
}

Example2: Want to inject B Obj to class and i have a constructor also.
Class X {
private B obj; 
@Inject public X(int arg1, B obj) {
 this.obj = obj;
}
```

---

```
class Module extends AbstarctModule {
void Configure() {
//How to use bind
}
```

Can someone please help me.

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this, they mainly hinge on whether `int arg1` is also injectable, or whether it is passed in by the user?  If the former then you have to bind `@Named("someName") int arg1`, if the latter you have to look into `Assisted Injection`.  Also, you should define better what you mean by `normal class`, referring to Scope?

Comment: HI, I want to inject B Obj to a class A where A is a simple class, its not sngleton. How to binf the module configuration method i am thinking

Comment: In your example B will inject into A just fine, the issue is the X constructor due to the `arg1` where you should have issues.  It also depends on the scope of A, if A is a singleton then B will effectively be a singleton.